# Why does py --version return a different version to python --version?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 4 versions of Python on my Windows desktop and was checking version using "py --version" from the command line which returned 3.9.1. I was confused by this as the one at the top of the list in my env variables is 3.11. However, when I ran "python --version" I did indeed get returned 3.11.

I would have expected "py --version" to be effectively the same command as "python --version" and to return the same result.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46027422/12317368

Comment: Okay I see now, thanks for link